# How to set up a development environment for React when IT won't allow you to install anything on your Windows workstation

Tags: linux, reactjs, windows, development-environment, environment

I am working for a client that does not allow setting up anything on the native Windows workstation.

I am, however, allowed to set up a virtual machine on which I can install anything I want.

So, I've set up a Linux VM and installed the React environment.

However, I would like to be able to use the native Windows tools that are allowed for development, since installing and using them on the VM is painfully slow.

I'm currently modifying the code with a native Windows IDE, then pushing the changes to a Git repository, then pulling the changes down to the Linux VM to see them work.  However, for debugging, where changes are added, removed, modified, etc... this is also painfully slow.

I tried to set up a shared folder to work on the code locally and having it update on the Linux VM dynamically, but that doesn't work because "npx create-react-app" does a bunch of things, like set up symlinks, that either don't work on a shared folder or aren't allowed by IT.  I'm guessing it's the shared Windows folder that's limiting this.  I also tried to set up a Samba share of the Linux folder, but I think this is blocked by IT, because I just can't see it from my Windows machine, and network discovery is turned on.

So, now that you know my pain, what would be the best way to set up a React development environment in this situation?  Help...

Comment: `I would like to be able to use the native Windows tools that are allowed for development` what tools?

Comment: To be honest, I would just use https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Atom or NetBeans or any decent IDE, anything other than vi.  It's not so much the tools, because I could install NetBeans on the VM, but it runs really slowly.  So the tools aren't relevant to the question it's more about the environment itself.  I want to be able to use a mature and comprehensive IDE with code highlight and such, natively on Windows, have the code update without going through Git for things like debugging and be able to see the page re-render when the code is modified in a Windows browser, which I'm able to do.

Comment: @GBWDev, is codesandbox secure and does it allow communication to a local web service?  I think the environment would have to be able to all run natively within the local network.  IT is pretty locked down here.

Answer (score 0):

I almost understands nothing about linux and VM, but here is something you can do.

When creating a react application with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), when you run `npm start`, your application will be hosted in `localhost:3000`.

So to do what you want, you need to set up the enviroment in the VM (e.g. create-react-app) and then configure (this is the part I don't understand how to do) your VM in a way you can access the VM's localhost and the files of your project.

This way you can edit the files of the VM and also see the app changing in the windows browser.

[How to share VM's folder with host](https://superuser.com/questions/662579/editing-files-on-virtual-machine)
[How access VM's localhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196118/how-to-access-localhost-on-virtualbox-host-machine)

Comment: That's exactly what I have set up.  I can view the app in a native Windows browser (http://ip_address_of_the_VM:3000).  When I update the files by pulling them from the Git repo, I see the app re-render.  However, I can't put the code in a folder in a way that just saving the modifications is communicated through to the VM.  I keep getting the following error whenever I try to do either, "npx create-react-app" or when I copy the code and do a "npm install" on the code folder:

"Maximum call stack size exceeded"

It's not a permissions issue. I tried both with "sudo", no change.

Comment: You shouldn't be controlling the files from git, but in windows you should change the VM files directly, so when you save on windows, it changes the files on the VM and also reload the app

Comment: How?  In the original question, I've covered all the things I've tried to do that and all the issues I've had.  Can you propose something I haven't already tried?

Comment: @user7547701 please take a look at the link I provided on [How to share folder](https://superuser.com/questions/662579/editing-files-on-virtual-machine). This way you will be able to edit the files of your VM in windows